# Notification sent successfully but not reveiving in Android from Firebase

Tags: php, android, firebase, cakephp, notifications

I am uploading video in my database and sending a notification, but the notification is not receiving in mobile.

Code:

```
$header = array(
  'header' => array(
    'Authorization'=>'key='.'AAAABxjSQes:APA91bHy_qL4s0BGkiGyCq57fXYtZxzWpfTzRsHZ9AnULieeP1nScb_vuAIYtXob7LEGvvrwBdue5g24iSGDTJGWUG6YcPnAqVx76EKdb5C2P3kl2mF5SrRDAvPWFv0Uqu-HmmVc4wsH',
    'Content-Type'=>'application/json'
  )
);
$http = new HttpSocket();
$results = $http->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', '{
  "to" : "cvhXVxTGLl8:APA91bG_iaWHfcka48YwkQPN1kDSIDTk1UAzc-QpHPpnhOPvKBruxnTC_Mxo49EJ3ih2pd9_kGIygs6J_cqMP2ZvoK2I9QVILZH97H8ovsCIuKtDFIr-4jKmBxZJ6E6SeuI_5T3XbfHz",
  "priority" : "high",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
  }

}', $header);
```

Output:

```
{"multicast_id":5769969831923920749,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1499773517218412%4e07cf6cf9fd7ecd"}]}
[context] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Firebase Receiving code 
Check your service class for receive notification and define it in Manifest file

**Mainfest**

```html
<service android:name="CustomFirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                    <action android:name=".SplashActivity" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

**Check Service Class CustomFirebaseMessagingService.class**

```html
public class CustomFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        private static final String TAG = CustomFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        private int notificationID = 100;
        private int numMessages = 0;
        String title, message;
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
                title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
                message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            }

            // Check if message contains a notification payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
                title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
                message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            }
            
   //create custom notification code
            displayNotification(getApplicationContext(),title,message);

        }

        protected void displayNotification(Context context, String PUSH_TITLE, String PUSH_MSG) {
            Log.i("Start", "notification");

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

           /* Invoking the default notification service */
            NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(PUSH_TITLE);
            mBuilder.setContentText(PUSH_MSG);
            mBuilder.setTicker("Message from Promo Caribbean");
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_top_notification);
            mBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);

            /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
            mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);
   NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle notiStyle = new
                        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
                //notiStyle.setBigContentTitle(PUSH_TITLE);
                notiStyle.bigText(PUSH_MSG);
                mBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle);            
            /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(SplashActivity.class);

            /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

           /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: sir i am using php

Comment: notification receiving code is from android side not from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and turned out that the problem was in the **channel ID** that you use when you create notification object. That is, I was using the different channel id which was not created in the app.

So the solution was to create App class that inherits from Application class and create channel ID there.

```
class App: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel()
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val name = "UPDATES"
        val descriptionText = "Updates to system objects"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

        val channel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "B1_SYSTEM_UPDATES"
    }
```

Then use that created notification channel in my onMessageReceived method:

```
class FcmService: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build()

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(Random.nextInt(), notification)
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    }
}
```